# Recuperar contraseña weblogic local

Tags: weblogic

Desgraciadamente olvidé la clave de la consola de weblogic en mi ambiente local y no puedo recuperarla de ninguna forma, no quiero desinstalar oracle de mi laptop y he buscado algunas formas de recuperar la contraseña pero hasta el momento nada ha resultado.

Principalmente averigüe que podía modificar mi contraseña en el archivo

boot.propertie en la ruta

```
C:\oracle\user_projects\domains\my_domain\servers\dominio1\security
```

pero no me ha resultado, alguien ha tenido el mismo problema??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Efectivamente, se hace modificando el fichero boot.properties en el directorio/carpeta security. Pero hay que hacer más cosas. Dejo un enlace que te guiará correctamente para hacer un reset de la cuenta admin en weblogic

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/reset-the-adminserver-password-in-weblogic-11g-and-12c